# Input button not submitting with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, html

php I have the following code

```
<form id="one" method="POST" action="#">

<input type="text" name="rfc" />

<button type="submit" name="selection" value="1">Option 1 </button>
<button type="submit" name="selection" value="2">Option 2 </button>
<input type="submit" name="selection" value="4" />

</form>

<section id="new_section"></section>
      <script>
        $('#one').submit(function(event){
          var data = $(this).serialize();
          $.post('two.php', data)
          .success(function(result){
              $('#new_section').html(result);
          })
          .error(function(){
              console.log('Error loading page');
          })
          return false;
        });
      </script>
```

In two.php I verify the values of rfc and selection fields

two.php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

And print_r only shows the rfc but not the selection , the output is the following:

> Array ( [rfc] => WIRK510828 )

Is this happening because of the action=# ?

Comment: I think you should change the button to a input of type submit.

Comment: What are the two `<button>` tags used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you should pass the button's values separately, because the serialize() doesn't take the buttons values.

first you have add and id or class to each button
Use `serializeArray();` instead of `serialize()`.

do something like this on your html, it works I just tested it:

```
<form id="one" method="POST" action="#">

    <input type="text" name="rfc" />

    <button type="submit" id="button1" name="selection" value="1">Option 1 </button>
    <button type="submit" id="button2" name="selection" value="2">Option 2 </button>
    <button type="submit" id="button4" name="selection" value="4">option 4</button>

</form>
<section id="new_section"></section>


<script>
var frm = $('#one');
var data = frm.serializeArray();
$('#button1, #button2, #button4').on("click",function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

frm.submit(function(event){
  $.post('two.php', data)
  .success(function(result){
      $('#new_section').html(result);
  })
  .error(function(){
      console.log('Error loading page');
  })
  return false;
});
data.push({name: encodeURI($(this).attr('name')), value: encodeURI($(this).attr('value'))});
frm.submit();
data.pop();
});
</script>
```

**explanation:**
I use the `data.push();` to push the extradata (the buttons values) into the `serializeArray();` then use `frm.submit()` to send the form and finally `data.pop()` to clean the array for future uses. I have also added some variables for better implementation.