# Two buttons in one form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use two submit buttons in one form. Doesn't sound hard... that's what I thought, too. It seems the variable of the submit buttons won't get send.
It works fine with just one button or no differentiation for the buttons.

The message.js is just to show a toastr error/success message.

form_handler.php :

```html
<?php 

require_once ('dbconnect.php');


 $nr = $_POST["nr"];

    $description = $_POST["description"];

 $price = $_POST["price"];

 $size = $_POST["size"];



if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "Add") {

 if(isset($_POST["nr"], $_POST["description"], $_POST["price"])){

  $sql =" INSERT INTO artikelstamm (nr, description, size, price) VALUES ('$nr', '$description', '$size', '$price')";

  $ergebnis = mysqli_query($db_link, $sql);
   //or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db_link));

  if(!$ergebnis){
   header('Content-type: text/javascript');

          $arr = array(
                  'message'    => '...',
                  'title'      => 'Error'
              );

              echo json_encode($arr);

  }else{
   header('Content-type: text/javascript');

       $arr = array(
           'message'    => '...',
           'title'      => 'Success'
       );

       echo json_encode($arr);
  }

 }

} elseif (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "Delete") {

 print_r($_POST);

}
```

HTML:

```html
<!-- Content -->

  <article class="first">

    <h2>Article</h2>

  </article>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="9u skel-cell-important">
          <?php                  require_once('article/showArticles.php');   
          ?>
  </div>
  <div class="3u">
       <section>
    Form here<br /><br />
   <form action="form_handler.php" method="post" id="schuma">
      <input type="text" name="nr" placeholder="Nr" /><br />
      <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description" /><br />
         <input type="text" name="size" placeholder="Size" /><br />
      <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price" /><br />
      <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
      <input id="btnDel" type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
   </form>

   <script src="article/message.js"></script>            
    </section>
  </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

message.js :

```html
$('#schuma').on('submit', function(){

    var that = $(this),

        contents = that.serialize();


    $.ajax({

        url: 'form_handler.php',

        type: 'POST',

        data: contents,

        dataType: 'JSON',

        success: function(data) {

     console.log(data)

            toastr.options = {

                "closeButton": true,

                "debug": false,

                "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width",

                "onclick": null,

                "showDuration": "20000",

                "hideDuration": "20000",

                "timeOut": "20000",

                "extendedTimeOut": "20000",

                "showEasing": "swing",

                "hideEasing": "linear",

                "showMethod": "fadeIn",

                "hideMethod": "fadeOut"

            }

            if(data.title == "Success"){

                toastr.success(data.message, data.title);

            }

            else{

                toastr.error(data.message, data.title);

            }

        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

EDIT: New Code

Comment: in form_handler.php before if try to print the post array like this: `print_r($_POST);` to see what you receive in POST in each case.

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you please emphasize? Im not understanding what you mean by your comment.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your code. It should work the way it is.

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` just shows the names and values of the `<input type="text"`. The `$_POST` won't get send...

Comment: @Skar can you give us some feedback? What browser are you using?

Comment: @CodeGodie I am using Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @Skar what do you mean by _"print_r($_POST); just shows the names and values of the <input type="text". The $_POST won't get send..."_ Can you edit your original post and show the actual results of `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: It just shows it like this: `nr=&description=&size=&price=` without anything added in the text fields. If i write anything in the fields it show the content
I meant that there is no value (or anything) for the `$_POST` variable of the submit buttons.

Comment: @Skar — Is that a complete test case? Or do you have some JavaScript in play that you haven't shared with us? (Since the code you've shared doesn't have `nr`, `description`, `size` or `price` fields, it seems like you are testing different code to what you are showing us)

Comment: I suspect that the problem lies with `<script src="article/message.js"></script>` (which we can't see)

Comment: Added the message.js - Sorry about the "chaos", many words are in german so i am trying to translate some real quick

Comment: AHA! theres something. You are using JS/AJAX to submit the form.

Comment: Sounds great ;) could you give me some hints or an explanation what i have to do now or provide the needed code? I am still learning all this and try to teach myself most of it :)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335763/input-button-not-submitting-with-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this took a while because you werent showing all your code. It seems that your `form` is actually being submitted through AJAX, not through PHP as you originally showed. You are disabling the form's way of submitting and using AJAX to submit, which is perfectly fine, however in your AJAX you are using `.serialize()` to obtain all your formdata, the problem is that `.serialize()` will not include the button with `type="submit"`. Therefore your PHP ending up with that field not set.

To fix this, you need to modify your JS and manually insert that info to the content sent. We can do this with `.serializeArray()` in the following manner:

```
$('form#schuma input[type=submit]').click(function () {

    var contents = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
    contents.push({name: "submit", value: this.value});

    $.ajax({
        url: 'form_handler.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: contents,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            // your other code
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't really aware of that and did not get how everything is connected with each other. 
Much to learn, i still have ;P
I am going to test it and get back to you after that :)

Comment: No problem. Let me know.

Comment: Sweet. Im glad I was able to help. Please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to my answer if you found this helped. :)

Comment: The differentiation works fine, but it seems the error/success message wont display anymore. It just displays the json message on a blank page.
It was defintiely very helpful :)

Comment: since you are specifying  `dataType: 'JSON',` you might also need to modify your PHP headers, so before the `echo json..` do `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: awesome Glad i helped.

Comment: Is it possible to change the Javascript code to be used with the <button> attribute?

Comment: yeah. if you change your HTML `input type=submit` to a `<button type=submit>` element than in JS you can do `$('button')....`

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is better to give the same name:

```
<input id="btnAdd" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
<input id="btnDel" type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
```

And in the PHP, you can check:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "Add") {
  // Do add
} elseif (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "Delete") {
  // Do delete
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I would like to know why is this approach wrong. Thanks. If someone doesn't agree with the answer, kindly let me know why. I just checked this and it works fine. `:)`

Comment: Sorry, finger trouble, not intended to DV, just a woops

Comment: Thats the button I intended to hit

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks buddy! `:P` Same two button at the same place problem. LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am a bit confused.. whats wrong with OP's original code? It seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @CodeGodie Having one single name, is lot better and easy to manage. There's a problem with `isset` and Internet Explorer.

Comment: right but whats wrong with it at the moment? Why isnt it working?

Comment: @CodeGodie I don't find a reason now why this doesn't work.

Comment: thats weird.. I tried OPs original code locally both on Chrome and IE, and they both work fine to me.

Comment: I tried this out and it doesn't work either. Like i said in my commentat the first answer: The `$_POST` of the buttons won't get send...

Comment: @Skar Can you kindly show the full HTML and your PHP code?

Comment: @Skar Looking for the full `form_handler.php`.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I am on it, just give me a moment :)

Comment: @Skar Sure. No problem.